What graphs or stacked polyhedra could better represent these totative & cototative Symmetries?
I expect it is well known that the tuples of the totatives and co-totatives of a number form symmetrical pairs that also sum to n. I have seen plots of the co-prime lattice before and I know this isn’t new. However it occurs to me that orthogonal plottings fail to leverage these symmetries or provide lines of attack.
I decided to plot the totatives and co-totatives of n on the edges of concentric hexagonal numbers to form 6 equilateral triangles (with 1 and n wrapping over the vertices). totatives and co-totatives of n on the edges of concentric hexagonal numbers to form 6 equilateral triangles. Here the plotting now has 3 lines of reflective symmetry down the centre of the equilateral triangles as well 3 lines of symmetry along the vertices of the hexagonal rings.
The interesting insight is that there are an additional 12 lines of reflective symmetry along the vertex edges but offset by +-1 for each of the equilateral triangles. Essentially, the internal coprimality sequences of n hit these lines of symmetry at 60 degrees and are reflected into the coprimality structure of the subsequent integers in an infinite recursion.
I believe this could provide a Pythagorean line of attack for relating primes to previous primes via squares and right angle structures also appear present. I expect there is a better way of describing the offsets using modulus residues. The integer partitioning of the tuples could also be potentially leveraged. I know that there are summative totient functions but it occurs to me that a recursive totient function or some kind of construction using the totatives and co-totatives as continued fractions could relate the entire plot to pi^2. What I find striking about this plotting is how complex it becomes from extremely simple starting conditions. Are there  better tiling methods or a 3d representation that makes things more intelligible. Naively, I believe the reflective symmetry could be captured from the perspective of a truncated hexagonal pyramid/ prism
